# Modifying a column data in Spark 1.6.1 DataFrame based on the same column value of different Row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image: This is the sorted data I have]

[This is the sorted data I have (above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if3Tx.png) is partitioned by id, ordered by date, seq. Now based on event, I want to change the value of price and size.
I want only one row per id, where:

1. If the latest event is 'add' or 'modify', then the price and size will be same.
2. But if the event is 'cancel', then I want the size to be added for each subsequent cancel, and subtracted from the latest add or modify of the same id. and the price for the same be updated to the price of the latest add/modify of the same id.

This is only a sample data I have.

Comment: I am just new to asking question, so please if you need any more information, please ask.

Comment: So for starters don't post images unless it is about UI. Instead please provide a [mcve].